# Calling a dll with a void* from C#

Tags: c#, c, void

I've read most of the hints but I can't get it to work.

I have a native C dll with this prototype:

```
int utl_Conv_HexString(U8 u8_Mode, void* DataIn, void* DataOut, int *piInOutLen, int maxOutLen);
```

This dll converts several string formats in byte arrays:

The dll is used in a system with unmanaged code (written in C)

Now I would like to use this dll in a C# / WPF Enviroment.

I still use other dll's in C#, but all have prototypes with no `void*`.

Examples from C:

```
//ByteArr to Telegramm

u8_Dst[0] = 0xAA;
u8_Dst[1] = 0xBB;
u8_Dst[2] = 0xCC;

u32_InOutLen = 3;
s32_res = utl_Conv_HexString(UTL_CONV_BYTEARR_TO_TELEGRAM, u8_Dst, ac8_Src, &u32_InOutLen, sizeof(ac8_Src));
```

or

```
strcpy(ac8_Src, "0xAA,0xBB,0xCC");
memset(u8_Dst, 0, sizeof(u8_Dst));
s32_res = utl_Conv_HexString(UTL_CONV_TELEGRAM_TO_BYTEARR, ac8_Src, u8_Dst, &u32_InOutLen, sizeof(u8_Dst));
```

My problem is that I can not figure out how this could be used in C#

Comment: Use `byte[]` for `void*`, `ref int` for `int*`

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like:

```
public enum U8
{
    UTL_CONV_BYTEARR_TO_TELEGRAM = 1, // TODO
    UTL_CONV_TELEGRAM_TO_BYTEARR = 2,
}
```

(you will have to put here your constants...)

```
[DllImport("SomeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int utl_Conv_HexString(U8 u8Mode, byte[] dataIn, byte[] dataOut, ref int piInOutLen, int maxOutLen);
```

(note that the `CallingConvention` could be `StdCall`... you'll have to check your code)

and then:

```
byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC");
byte[] dest = new byte[64];
int lenSrc = src.Length;
int res = utl_Conv_HexString(U8.UTL_CONV_TELEGRAM_TO_BYTEARR, src, dest, ref lenSrc, dest.Length);
```

The `void*` is normally translated to a `byte[]`.